# Select groups that satisfy one of the two conditions using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, data-cleaning

I want to select groups that satisfy one of the two conditions: 1) contain `a` and `b`; 2) contain `a` and `c`. Here is the dataset:

```
ff <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), value = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "c"))
```

Therefore the selected groups should be 2 and 3.

How to achieve that in an efficient way (I have a much larger dataset)?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You can combine conditions using `&` for AND, `|` for OR.

Comment: This didn't work: `ff %>%
  filter(all(c("a", "b") %in% value) | all(c("a", "c") %in% value))` @Rhesous

Comment: If you want to do it "by group", then you need to use `group_by(id)` before your filter. (or `.by = id` in your `filter()`.)

Comment: or add a `.by = id)` in your filter to make it look per `id` group. (since dplyr 1.1.0)

Comment: What is much larger dataset do you mean - can you add more details information you about the performance issues you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can groupby and filter by those two conditions a suggested

```
library dplyr

ff <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), 
                 value = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "c"))

ff %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(c("a", "b") %in% value) | all(c("a", "c") %in% value)) %>%
  distinct(id)
```

Basically, your filter is checking for all instances of a and b or a and c in the value in the group ID.

The distinct produces the unique groups from the filter code above